# WSO2 Identity server integration with LDAP and DB

Tags: database, ldap, wso2, integration, wso2-identity-server

Just had a query that can WSO2 Identity Server be integrated with both LDAP and DB at the same time. To elaborate my query more, say we have a group of users defined in LDAP and another group of users defined in DB and I want Identity Server to act authorization gateway for both of these groups. Is it possible?

Also, while integrating with DB WSO2 adds its own tables in our existing DB. Is there any way we can add custom attributes(claims) support in DB without altering the WSO2 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server supports only one active user realm at a given time. But if your requirement is to use WSO2 IS as an authorization gateway which connects to a LDAP server as well to a DB for populating claims, etc then it is possible to use XACML support in WSO2 IS with a custom PIP(policy information point). In that case, you can connect to the LDAP server as the primary user store and write a custom PIP to connect to the DB to read the required claims.

Following two posts on PIPs will be helpful.

[1] - http://xacmlinfo.com/2011/12/18/understanding-pip/
[2] - http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/04/xacml-policy-information-point.html

Answering the second query, with the default configuration in the JDBC mode, WSO2 IS uses its own set of tables for maintaining its user store. But if required, you can write your own user store implementation which connects to your database.